# php check if file exist: check only portion

Tags: php, file-exists

in php we can check if file exist using

```
if(file_exists("destination/"))
{
    condition
}
```

but what I wanted to do is...

for example I already have this file on my destination

```
hello_this_is_filename(2).doc
```

how would I know if there is a file in that directory having a name containing a character

```
hello_this_is_filename
```

I wanted to search that way because... if there is exists on that directory, what will I do is... renaming the file into

```
hello_this_is_filename(3).doc
```

I also need to count the existence of my search so I know what number I'm going to put like

```
(3), (4), (5) and so on
```

any help?

Comment: http://php.net/glob would probably be of some use here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
if (count(glob("destination/hello_this_is_filename*.doc"))) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging Marc B's suggestion and xdazz, I would do something as follows:

```
<?php
$files = glob("destination/hello_this_is_filename*");
if (count($files)) {
   sort($files);

   // last one contains the name we need to get the number of
   preg_match("([\d+])", end($files), $matches);

   $value = 0;
   if (count($matches)) {
      // increment by one
      $value = $matches[0];
   }

   $newfilename = "destination/hello_this_is_filename (" . ++$value . ").doc";
?>
```

Sorry this is untested, but thought it provides others with the regexp work to actually do the incrementing...